# How to use in C# the method or function of a webservice which returns XML response in the web browser when calling the link of this webservice

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I am trying to use functions that a web service returns in an XML format, I just want to know how can I call or use a function in that XML response from the web service in my C# application.

For example, use of `ADD` function which adds two numbers A and B, in my C# app.

Here's an example:

```
   <s:element name="AddInteger">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" name="Arg1" type="s:long"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" name="Arg2" type="s:long"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

Comment: I asume that you want to work with the result data and not call the actual function in the webservice. I would recommend using a XMLSerializer (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=net-6.0), which allows you to deserialize your XML string as a class.

Comment: ok, thanks for your request, to be simple . if a webservice provide the function ADD to add two numbers, when i put the link in a web browser it return the fuction in a xml format. if i want to add two numerbs in my C# app i must call the function and pass it the two parameters. my problem is that i do not know how to call the function of the webservice in my app and pass it the two parameters wich are the two numbers

Answer (score 0):

You need c# classes to deserialize results.  Below is the code.  You can also include the classes in a Controller. The controller will automatically do the deseriale.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication40
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add(string.Empty, "http://tempuri.org");
            ns.Add("s", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
            ns.Add("SOAP-ENV", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));

            string responseTextXml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(responseTextXml);
            XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(sReader);
            Envelope envelope = (Envelope)serializer.Deserialize(xReader);

            Envelope add = new Envelope()
            {
                Body = new Body()
                {
                    request = new List<AddInteger>() {
                       new AddInteger() { Arg1 = 3, Arg2 = 4}
                    }
                }
            };
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter();
            XmlWriter xWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sWriter, settings);
            serializer.Serialize(xWriter, add,ns);

            string xml2 = sWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }

    }
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "AddIntegerResponse", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org")]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "AddIntegerResult", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org")]
        public List<AddIntegerResult> results { get; set; }

        [XmlArray(ElementName = "AddIntegerRequest", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "AddInteger", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")]
        public List<AddInteger> request { get; set; }
    }
    public class AddIntegerResult
    {
        public int value { get; set; }
    }
    public class AddInteger
    {
        public long Arg1 { get; set; }
        public long Arg2 { get; set; }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks for your request, to be simple . if a webservice provide the function ADD to add two numbers, when i put the link in a web browser it return the fuction in a xml format. if i want to add two numerbs in my C# app i must call the function and pass it the two parameters. my problem is that i do not know how to call the function of the webservice in my app and pass it the two parameters wich are the two numbers

Comment: You need to serialize the classes and create new class for AddInteger.  I will update code.

Comment: thanks @jdweng, am sorry the filename here isnt a file that i have on my pc, but it is an xml that displayed in the browser when i call the url link of the web service...     here is the url  link of the web service that i would like to use : _(https://www.crcind.com/csp/samples/SOAP.Demo.CLS?WSDL=1)_      could you please have a look

Comment: The variable xml2 is a string with the xml text that will go into the body of the request SOAP.  The link you provided is just a definition file of the methods and not the code.  Your example is a partial schema of the methods (taken from the definition file).  I think my xml needs some modifications but no sure how you are suppose to wrap the AddInteger in the SOAP.  The definition files has a lot of similar methods and do not know which methods you are suppose to use.  You should be following what you were taught.  There are many different ways of sending a request/response in c#.