# SOAP: How to control default namespace versioning

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I have a simple SOAP function:

```
ExamCard examCard = new ExamCard();
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("output.ExamCard", FileMode.Create);
SoapFormatter soapFormatter = new SoapFormatter();
soapFormatter.Serialize(fileStream, examCard);
```

When I run this code I see in the output XML that I get:

```
[...]
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<a1:ExamCard id="ref-1" xmlns:a1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/Philips.PmsMR.ExamCards.ECModel/philips.pmsmr.examcards.ecmodel_cs%2C%20Version%3D1.0.0.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3Dnull">
[...]
```

However I would like to generate instead:

```
[...]
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<a1:ExamCard id="ref-1" xmlns:a1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/Philips.PmsMR.ExamCards.ECModel/philips.pmsmr.examcards.ecmodel_cs">
[...]
```

Is there a way in C# to control this default namespace generation based on assemblyname ? In the end I'd like to get rid of the extra `%2C%20Version%3D1.0.0.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3Dnull`.

Comment: See following on how to handle namespace : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74036543/how-to-use-in-c-sharp-the-method-or-function-of-a-webservice-which-returns-xml-r/74036679#74036679

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to fix the string.  The %2C%20 are just a comma and a space. You could just use input.Replace("%2C%20", ", ").  Someplace in your code you have a object with a name that contains spaces and commas and the code automatically substitutes the ascii value for these characters.

```
            string input = "%2C%20Version%3D1.0.0.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3Dnull";
            string pattern = @"%(?'byte'[a-fA-F0-9]{2})";
            string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "&#x${byte};");
            string results = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(output);
```